# Writing a class to pass add_action arguments in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, class, hook, parameter-passing

I'm using the hook `user_register` that writes to the variable `$user_id`.  I want to call this hook inside a function and pass the variable `$pass` from the parent function to the function `register_pass`.  Once there, `$pass` and `user_id` will be sent to third party software as per their protocol.

**The key goal is** to get both `$pass` and `$user_id` into the same array to be sent out via SOAP.

```
function random_pass_save($pass){

    add_action( 'user_register', 'regiser_pass')
    function register_pass($user_id){
        .
        .
        .
        code that processes both the $user_id, AND $pass and sends it to another piece of software
        .
        .
        .
    }

}
```

Now I have done a bit of reading on this and I keep having people recommend using classes to pass variables around from add_action calls to parent functions and so on.  In principle this makes sense; as I understand it, you can pretty much access the class everywhere (sort of like a global variable but a lot less precarious).  However, I'm just not understanding how to apply the examples that I've seen to my situation.  I haven't used classes before and so I was wondering if anyone would be kind enough to walk me through this particular application.

Comment: You are cross-posting the same question here and in [wordpress.se]. And you already have feedback over there. [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/185667). Answer: no.

Comment: @brasofilo My apologies if my posting ran afoul of standard etiquette.  I figured that this situation was appropriate because, in my question on Wordpress Answers, I was asking a broad "what's a technique to accomplish X" question.  After googling some, I found info on Stackoverflow that classes could do the trick but was unsure of how to apply them to the situation at hand. Given that I found the leads on stackoverflow, I figured it would be good to ask there. But, as a much more senior member on both sites than me, you'd likely have a better intuition on this; I'll be mindful in the future

Comment: Ok, I see the difference, close vote retracted. But your sample code seems invalid, why do you have a function inside a function? And reading further, what are you trying to accomplish? Why do you need to store the ID of a newly registered user?

Comment: @brasofilo Wow, thanks for reconsidering; I do see your point about cross-posting though and it's good for noobs like me to keep in mind.  Anyway, to the technical stuff:  I'm integrating openmeetings (open source web-conferencing) with wordpress, in such a way that each wordpress user is recorded as an external user in the openmeetings system.  The function-in-a-function allows me to use a hook to grab the plain text of the auto-generated password and then use a second hook to catch the data from the actual generation of the user.  I rewrite the question above after cleaning up my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding this right, you simply need to call a custom function when a user is created. The functions don't have to be nested and it doesn't matter if this is a class or not.

Add the hook and inside its callback, you call your function passing the data:

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'register_pass' );

function register_pass( $user_id )
{
    $password = get_the_password_somehow_with( $user_id ); // <--- problem
    random_pass_save( $user_id, $password );
}

function random_pass_save( $user_id, $password )
{
    // do your thing
}
```

That problem can be solved with the hook `check_passwords`, that happens before `user_register` and that contains both the user name and the password.

But ok, let's do it in a Class, it's based in [this skeleton that I always use](https://gist.github.com/toscho/3804204/). All the explanation is in the code comments.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Testing a Singleton
 * Plugin URI:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19306582
 * Version:     0.1
 * Author:      brasofilo 
 * Author URI:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/12615/brasofilo
 */

# Start the plugin in a safe point
add_action( 
    'plugins_loaded',
    array( B5F_Demo_SO_19306582::get_instance(), 'plugin_setup' )
    );

class B5F_Demo_SO_19306582 
{
    # Singleton
    protected static $instance = NULL;  

    # Store new user data (id, name, password)
    private $user_data;  

    # Leave empty
    public function __construct() {}

    # Singleton
    public static function get_instance() 
    {
        NULL === self::$instance and self::$instance = new self;
        return self::$instance;
    }

    # Start our action hooks
    public function plugin_setup() 
    {
        add_action( 'check_passwords', array( $this, 'check_pass' ), 10, 3 );
        add_action( 'user_register',  array( $this, 'user_register_action' ) );
    }

    # Confirms that passwords match when registering a new user
    public function check_pass( $user, $pass1, $pass2 ) 
    {   
        // They match, let's add data to our private property
        if( $pass1 == $pass2 )
            $this->user_data = array( 'user' => $user, 'pass' => $pass1 );
    }

    # Add the ID of a newly registered user to our private property
    # Now we have all the data and can call our final method
    public function user_register_action( $user_id )
    {
        $this->user_data['user_id'] = $user_id;
        $this->external_save();
    }

    # In this method we do our thing with all the information 
    # previously stored in the private property
    public function external_save()
    {
        var_dump( $this->user_data );
        die();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for spelling it out like that.  I'm new to the world of web development (if you couldn't tell) so seeing a new concept laid out this specifically helps me out in the long run big-time.  Since I'm using a randomly generated password for new users, I had to add another function but no matter, it worked just fine.  For other folks taking a crack at singletons for the first time, I found [this youtube tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UPfdb5y2SOI) to be a really helpful supplement to the info above.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a function within a function; as others have stated, you can accomplish this with classes.

I'd suggest reading up on the Singleton pattern. Basically, you want an object that guarantees the presence of only one instance of itself. So let's say the class you use to store the new user's info is called UserCredentials. Once it's implemented as a Singleton, along with getters/setters for user/pass as appropriate, you can do:

```
function random_pass_save($pass) {
    UserCredentials::getSingleton()->savePass($pass);
}

add_action( 'user_register', 'regiser_pass')
function register_pass($user_id){
    $pass = UserCredentials::getSingleton()->getPass();
    // $user_id and $pass are now both in scope
}
```

As you inferred, the same thing can be accomplished by storing to $GLOBALS['whatever'], but this is cleaner.